# createReadStream send file http

Tags: file, node.js, stream

I'm trying to open an img file and send it through http. I have read that the best method for doing it is creatReadStream because it's async and better for performance.

Here it's my code:

```
var file = fs.createReadStream(image);

    file.on("error", function(err){
        ...
    });

    res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type" : "image/png"});

    file.on("data", function(data) {
        res.write(data);
    })

    file.on("end", function() {
        res.end();
    })
```

How can I know the file size to let res know in order to send it in the headers?

I don't like having writehead not in a callback, what can I do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var stat = fs.statSync('path/to/imagefile');
response.writeHead(200, {
  'Content-Type' : 'image/png',
  'Content-Length': stat.size
});
fs.createReadStream('path/to/imagefile').pipe(response);
```

Answer (score 8):

The `res.writeHead()` call is in the right place but the event listeners could be replaced with `file.pipe(res);` as you are only forwarding the data from the read stream to the write stream of the `res`. Also the HTTP response code `202` doesn't seem appropriate why not use `200`.

```
var file = fs.createReadStream(image);
res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type" : "image/png"});
file.pipe(res);
```

Comment: What's the advantage?

Comment: @fabiomaia Of using pipe over explicitly setting up event listeners? It is easier to get right. Sure you can do it explicitly but you'll have to do everything pipe does so if you go that way read the implementation of pipe.

Answer (score 1):

@wayne Thank you so much for your answer but wouldn't be better to use stat asynchronously?

```
var stat = fs.stat(image, function(err,stats) {
        if (err) {
            req_error(res,err);
        } else {
            res.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type' : 'image/png',
            'Content-Length': stats.size
            });

            var file = fs.createReadStream(image);
            file.pipe(res);
        };
    });
```

Comment: yes, use async whenever possible. I am not using async because I have this part of code in two callbacks, so for simplicity I do stateSync.